# Simplesamlphp copy is required both side?

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I have implemented simplesamlphp successfully using SQL authentication module.

My question is i have impliment simplesamlphp two website one is www.test1.com and another is www.test2.com it available in different Host/Server so simplesamlphp application copy it is required to both side or not.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to copy it both sides, as 1 is your `Service Provider` and the other one is your `Identity Provider`

Here are the links to configure SP and IDP using SingleSAMLPhp,

1. [SingleSAMLPHP as Service Provider](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.8/simplesamlphp-sp)
2. [SingleSAMLPHP as Identity Provider](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.8/simplesamlphp-idp)

For a quick installation Refer [SimplSAMLPhp-install](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.8/simplesamlphp-install)